# How to implement BlazeFace?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

[BlazeFace](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05047) is a lightweight and well-performing face detector tailored for mobile GPU inference. It runs at a speed of 200-1000+ FPS on flagship devices. How to implement BlazeFace in Mathematica?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
singleBlazeBlock[ch1_, ch2_, stride_: 1, pad_: 0] := NetGraph[
  <|
   1 -> NetChain[
     {
      ConvolutionLayer[ch1, {5, 5}, "ChannelGroups" -> ch1, 
       "Stride" -> stride, "PaddingSize" -> 2],
      BatchNormalizationLayer[],
      ConvolutionLayer[ch2, {1, 1}],
      BatchNormalizationLayer[]
      }
     ],
   2 -> NetChain[
     {
      PoolingLayer[{stride, stride}, stride],
      PaddingLayer[{{pad, pad}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
      }
     ],
   3 -> ThreadingLayer[Plus],
   4 -> ElementwiseLayer[Ramp]
   |>,
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> {1, 2} -> 3 -> 4
   }
  ]

doubleBlazeBlock[ch1_, ch2_, ch3_, ch4_, stride_: 1, pad_: 0] := 
 NetGraph[
  <|
   1 -> NetChain[
     {
      ConvolutionLayer[ch1, {5, 5}, "ChannelGroups" -> ch1, 
       "Stride" -> stride, "PaddingSize" -> 2],
      BatchNormalizationLayer[],
      ConvolutionLayer[ch2, {1, 1}],
      BatchNormalizationLayer[],
      ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
      ConvolutionLayer[ch3, {5, 5}, "ChannelGroups" -> ch3, 
       "Stride" -> 1, "PaddingSize" -> 2],
      BatchNormalizationLayer[],
      ConvolutionLayer[ch4, {1, 1}],
      BatchNormalizationLayer[]
      }
     ],
   2 -> NetChain[
     {
      PoolingLayer[{stride, stride}, stride],
      PaddingLayer[{{pad, pad}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
      }
     ],
   3 -> ThreadingLayer[Plus],
   4 -> ElementwiseLayer[Ramp]
   |>,
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> {1, 2} -> 3 -> 4
   }
  ]

net = NetGraph[
   <|
    1 -> NetChain[
      {
       ConvolutionLayer[24, {5, 5}, "Stride" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 2],
       ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
       BatchNormalizationLayer[]
       }
      ],
    2 -> singleBlazeBlock[24, 24],
    3 -> singleBlazeBlock[24, 24],
    4 -> singleBlazeBlock[24, 48, 2, 12],
    5 -> singleBlazeBlock[48, 48],
    6 -> singleBlazeBlock[48, 48],
    7 -> doubleBlazeBlock[48, 24, 24, 96, 2, 24],
    8 -> doubleBlazeBlock[96, 24, 24, 96],
    9 -> doubleBlazeBlock[96, 24, 24, 96],
    10 -> doubleBlazeBlock[96, 24, 24, 96, 2],
    11 -> doubleBlazeBlock[96, 24, 24, 96],
    12 -> doubleBlazeBlock[96, 24, 24, 96]
    |>,
   {
    NetPort["Input"] -> 
     1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12
    },
   "Input" -> {3, 128, 128}
   ] // NetInitialize
```

[image]

```
img = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 128, 128}];

net[img, TargetDevice -> "GPU"]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.0030011, Null}

net[img, TargetDevice -> "CPU"]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.0457831, Null}
```

*To be continued...*

Comment: Would you add all the NetTrain code and data/details to train it?